# What value for x will cause math.isfinite(x) to return False?

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, the `math.isfinite` function returns `True` if the argument passed is a finite number. I want to know expression or equation (equation that generates infinite value) which will return `False`, other than `'NAN'`. Passing a number divided by 0 will give error.

Comment: `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` are the positive and negative infinity values. Are you asking how to *produce* such a value from an expression?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know an equation or expression which produces such value.

Comment: Then it's just a duplicate of [Alternative methods of initializing floats to '+inf', '-inf' and 'nan'](//stackoverflow.com/q/51641287)

Comment: thanks for sharing the link....

Answer (score 2):

Before asking a question like this, you should always read the documentation. Simply using `help(math.isfinite)` in a REPL would tell you what values return False.

```
Help on built-in function isfinite in module math:

isfinite(...)
    isfinite(x) -> bool

    Return True if x is neither an infinity nor a NaN, and False otherwise.
```

Like Martijn Peters mentioned, `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` will both produce infinite values. And in Python 3.5+, you also have `math.inf` as a way to produce those values.

Comment: I would like know a valid equation or expression which generates infinite value and results this function to return false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create value of infinity you should use

```
float('inf') # positive infinity
```

These value below are all False

```
import math
math.isfinite(float('inf'))
math.isfinite(float('-inf'))
math.isfinite(float('nan'))
```